# nginx how to forward fcgi's `Content-Security-Policy` header from `x-accl-redirect`?

Tags: php, nginx, http-headers, fastcgi

## Question:

I have a *fcgi* application (php) sending the headers

```
Content-Security-Policy: sandbox;
Content-Type: foobar
X-Accel-Redirect: /test
```

and for some reason nginx is forwarding the `Content-Type` header, but it's not forwarding the `Content-Security-Policy: sandbox;` header

my php source code is:

```
<?php
header("Content-Security-Policy: sandbox;");
header("Content-Type: foobar");
header("X-Accel-Redirect: /test");
```

and the `test` file contains: `testcontent`

and when i hit it with `curl -v` i get:

```
$ curl paste.lan:81/test.php -v
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:81...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to paste.lan (127.0.0.1) port 81 (#0)
> GET /test.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: paste.lan:81
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Sun, 21 Feb 2021 14:26:35 GMT
< Content-Type: foobar
< Content-Length: 12
< Last-Modified: Sun, 21 Feb 2021 14:26:00 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: "60326d78-c"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< 
testcontent
* Connection #0 to host paste.lan left intact
```

so, any idea why nginx isn't forwarding the `Content-Security-Policy` header? or how to fix it?

---

---

## Solved with:

`add_header Content-Security-Policy $upstream_http_content_security_policy;`

I'm not sure why i have to do it with `Content-Security-Policy` and not with `Content-Type` but oh well...